# How to set a default value for a foreign key attribute for a table that does not exists yet in Django?

Tags: django, django-models

I have a pre-existing Django Model class, in which I need to add a one-to one relationship with another model class that is not created yet in the DB yet. 
I'm planning to fill the new model with some default values by cakking  function in urls.py, but I'm not sure about the id of those values that'll be generated in the DB to assign it as a default value to the foreign key.

Is it a good idea if I hardcode the value 1 as default assuming that the record A for the new model will have a PK value of 1?
Is it a better approach to this?

Comment: In that case it might be better to make it `NULL`-able, and use `NULL`, which means that the reference points to "nothing".

Comment: I mean, isn't any way to fetch and set  the default value at runtime when the model will be created in db for the first time?

Comment: Yes, you can use a callable as default, and thus make a query to obtain the first primary key. But still it is rather unstable, since that first record can be anything, not per se the most sensical one.

Comment: can you please define what you say, still catching up with django